# Count the number of rows above since the condition was true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume, I have a df with some integers:

`mdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('A'))`

And condition for them:

`mdf['CM'] = mdf['A'] > mdf['A'].shift(5)`

What it the most efficient way to count the number of rows above current since the  condition was true?

It should be like so:

```
def some_function(df):
  """
  Here is calculated nearest row index from current where the condition was met
  """
  return integer_value of None

mdf['SINCE'] = some_function(mdf)
```

UPD.
The df should look so:

```
Idx  A    CM    SINCE   Formula
0   23  False   None    
1   55  False   None    
2   48  False   None    
3   17  False   None    
4   24   True   0       4-4
5   30  False   1       5-4
6   99   True   0       6-6
7   11  False   1       7-6
8   47   True   0       8-8
9   25  False   1       9-8
10  78  False   2       10-8
11  40   True   0       11-11
12  99   True   0       12-12
13  7   False   1       13-12
14  6   False   2       14-12
15  64   True   0       15-15
16  62  False   1       16-15
17  39   True   0       17-17
18  41   True   0       18-18
19  28  False   1       19-18
```

Comment: @smci - reposted needed result in text format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
s = mdf['CM'].cumsum()
mdf["SINCE"] = mdf[s.gt(0)].groupby(s).cumcount()

print (mdf)
      A     CM  SINCE Formula
Idx                          
0    23  False    NaN     NaN
1    55  False    NaN     NaN
2    48  False    NaN     NaN
3    17  False    NaN     NaN
4    24   True    0.0     4-4
5    30  False    1.0     5-4
6    99   True    0.0     6-6
7    11  False    1.0     7-6
8    47   True    0.0     8-8
9    25  False    1.0     9-8
10   78  False    2.0    10-8
11   40   True    0.0   11-11
12   99   True    0.0   12-12
13    7  False    1.0   13-12
14    6  False    2.0   14-12
15   64   True    0.0   15-15
16   62  False    1.0   16-15
17   39   True    0.0   17-17
18   41   True    0.0   18-18
19   28  False    1.0   19-18
```

Comment: I need not the first True value, but distance between current row and the nearest above where the condition was met. It should be relative to current row index. In your example I get only first index for all rows.

Comment: @S.A. - Can you add some small data sample and mainly expected ouput with this data?

Comment: I ve updated the post and attached the picture with `SINCE` column and `Formula` column where is shown how the distance calculated (difference between index positions)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with cumulative sum:

```py
cs = mdf.CM.cumsum()
mdf["SINCE"] = mdf.groupby(cs).cumcount()

# Nonify the values up until first True
mdf.loc[cs == 0, "SINCE"] = np.nan
```

to get (for 30 sample data):

```
     A     CM  SINCE
0   79  False    NaN
1   46  False    NaN
2   59  False    NaN
3   31  False    NaN
4   72  False    NaN
5   34  False    NaN
6   42  False    NaN
7   40  False    NaN
8   82   True    0.0
9   16  False    1.0
10   9  False    2.0
11  45   True    0.0
12  68   True    0.0
13  48  False    1.0
14  20   True    0.0
15   9  False    1.0
16  14  False    2.0
17  91   True    0.0
18  92   True    0.0
19   0  False    1.0
20  93   True    0.0
21   1  False    1.0
22  60  False    2.0
23   0  False    3.0
24  93   True    0.0
25  85  False    1.0
26  52   True    0.0
27  32  False    1.0
28  65   True    0.0
29  85  False    1.0
```